# migrate database from Sqlite3 to Postgres = Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, sqlite

I have a small app that I have build and I am planning on transfering it to a live environment. This app scales really quickly. I currently have Sqlite3 as the database stack I am using for my project. I wanted to know if it is smart for me to switch to PostgreSQL before I host my project in a live environment. My app is currently running through docker images and sqlite3 works find on docker, but I feel like later on when I am dealing with lots of requests, PostgreSQL would be better off for me. If it is a good idea to switch from sqlite3 to PostgreSQL, I know I have to do the following lines, but I am not sure what I have to change in the django settings python page...:

```
python manage.py dumpdata > dump.json
```

Change DB connection string in settings.py to POSTGRES

```
python manage.py syncdb
python manage.py loaddata data.json

login to postgres db using psql
- execute this to delete all the data in the content_types table truncate 
django_content_type RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE;

python manage.py loaddata data.json
```

So would the settings.py file look something like this compared to current setup:

current:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

modded:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgres',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.postgres'),
    }
}
```

is that it for the changes that I have to do within the settings.py file. Do i need to add or change anything else...

Also how can I login to postgrs from within my django application locally....

Comment: You say your app scales quickly? So you stress tested it and can safely say it need or does not need pgSQL?  Is pgSQL better ? Perhaps it depends on your application and needs.

Comment: well i am going to start the beta testing soon. I was just wondering if sqlite3 three was a strong database for scalability, or should I switch my database to postgresQL. Also I want to host my project on AWS server and I think they only use postgrestql.. not sqlite3. or does it not matter because I am using docker..... @Namphibian

Comment: You should switch to Postgres, yes. But that is not how you use it in the settings.

Comment: so if i want to switch to postgres, what is the easiest way to do it. also i am planning on completely clearing my database from all of the testing accounts before beta testing... what is the best way to do this and are there any changes i habe to make within my django models or how i make queries.. @DanielRoseman

Comment: If you don't want to keep any data, then don't bother dumping the old data to a file. And the instructions for configuring it to use Postgres are in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases).